# My HTC Desire HD has been stolen. What data can still be accessed by the thief?

Tags: security, lock-screens, data-recovery, lost-phone

I have contacted the network and had the phone barred, I had applied a screen lock.  I am concerned however if the thief can still access all my numbers, texts, saved passwords and most importantly the pictures/videos of my daughter which were stored to the handset?  It terrifies me to think that some horror could access these for all kinds of use.

Comment: Since it is a Desire HD you should have "HTC Sense", if you log in via the web, I believe you can wipe data from the phone? As for what data (taking a stab here)... assuming they've gotten access, I guess any of the apps/sites you have already logged in. Also I assume anything on the SD Card is accessible (they can insert it into a computer and read the contents of the card)

Answer (score 3):

If the data was not encrypted: **everything**.

The data on the removable SD-card can be easily accessed, just like a lost USB-Memory-Stick. The internal flash storage can also be read out via some, *admittedly sophisticated but practical possible*, approaches.
AFAIK no Data that you sync with the Google cloud is encrypted.

**It's always wise to install some remote wipe tool, like pyko said. Even if they are not foolproof and can not provide a "secure delete" functionality, they provide some security and raise the bar to read out your data.**

Hint: The AN.SX [security tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security?sort=votes&pagesize=50) provides some further related information for such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Plan B](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb)? You can install it from the market after you've lost your phone and use it to find it's current location.

For your next phone, I would recommend [Cerberus](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus) - I [reviewed a bunch of security apps](http://www.nirdvana.com/2011/06/19/android-security-apps-review/), and it's definitely the clear winner.